# R Error: Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) : don't know how 'time1' is converted to class "“POSIXct”"

Tags: r, error-handling, posixct, difftime

I have a very simple difftime calculation that will not work. I am simply trying to find the difference between two lists of POSIXct datetimes:

```
ends <- list("2022-08-01 06:26:09", "2022-08-01 21:45:49","2022-08-01 23:42:59")
starts <- list("2022-08-01 00:05:59","2022-08-01 09:28:19","2022-08-01 22:14:39")

difftime(ends,starts, units = "mins")
```

But I am met with this error:

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) : don't know how 'time1' is converted to class "“POSIXct”".

This should be very simply but I can't find a work around. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Use `c()` to link the datetime strings instead of `list()`. Then run your code again.

Comment: the problem is these dates are extracted from a larger dataset in this format. do you know how I can convert a list of those datatimes to a concatenation so this code works no matter which list i extract?

Comment: How about `difftime(unlist(ends), unlist(starts), units = "mins")`